# Use character array to fill column values by row

Tags: arrays, r, string

One column of `big.data` (`year.60`) describes column name of desired value by row like this:

```
big.data= data.frame(ID= c(1,2), Y.1990= c(100, 120), 
Y.1991= c(NA, 125), Y.1992= c(115, 130), year.60= c("Y.1990", 
"Y.1991"), Y.60= c(NA, NA) )

big.data$year.60 = as.character(big.data$year.60)

big.data
#  ID   Y.1990 Y.1991 Y.1992  year.60 Y.60
#1  1      100     NA    115   Y.1990   NA
#2  2      120    125    130   Y.1991   NA
```

### How can I very simply make `Y.60` equal big.data$Y.1990 in row1 and big.data$Y.1991 in row2, etc. for 10,000 rows (i.e., `Y.60= year.60 by row)`?

```
big.data$Y.60= big.data[[year.60]]
Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) 
  as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
    object 'year.60' not found
```

### Real Data that does not work the way I expect

I want `skinny.data$Y.60` to hold `skinny.data$y.1970` in `skinny.data$Y.60[1,]`, `skinny.data$y.1953` in `skinny.data$Y.60[2,]`, `skinny.data$y.1963` in `skinny.data$Y.60[3,]`, `skinny.data$y.1993` in `skinny.data$Y.60[4,]`, etc. Yet even if I limit this to 5 rows, all methods below fail.

```
str(skinny.data)
'data.frame':  42001 obs. of  39 variables:
  $ Y.60     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
$ year.60    : chr  "y.1970" "y.1953" "y.1963" "y.1993" ...
$ y.1968      : num  10006 19467 19467 19467 19467 ...
$ y.1969      : num  NA 18994 18994 18994 18994 ...
$ y.1970      : num  NA 23150 23150 23150 23150 ...
$ y.1971      : num  NA 15041 15041 15041 25773 ...
$ y.1972      : num  NA 17183 17183 NA 17183 ...
$ y.1973      : num  NA 14354 14354 NA 14354 ...
$ y.1974      : num  NA 6829 6829 NA 6829 ...
$ y.1975      : num  NA 9444 9444 NA 9444 ...
$ y.1976      : num  NA 3717 3717 NA 9294 ...
$ y.1977      : num  NA 0 0 NA 2636 ...
$ y.1978      : num  NA 0 0 NA 4125 ...
$ y.1979      : num  NA 3394 3394 NA 12577 ...
$ y.1980      : num  NA 0 0 NA 4821 ...
$ y.1981      : num  NA 0 0 NA 7257 ...
$ y.1982      : num  NA 4778 4778 NA 8009 ...
# ...
# etc.

skinny.data.mini= skinny.data[1:5, ]

## mapply
skinny.data.mini$Y.60 <- 
  mapply(getElement, name=skinny.data.mini$year.60,
    data.frame(t(skinny.data.mini)))
# Error in `[[.default`(object, name, exact = TRUE) : 
#   subscript out of bounds

## quick vectorized approach
skinny.data.mini$Y.60 <- 
  skinny.data[cbind(seq_len(nrow(skinny.data.mini)), 
       match(skinny.data.mini$year.60, names(skinny.data.mini)))]
describe(skinny.data.mini$Y.60)
# Error in x - mx : non-numeric argument to binary operator
# In addition: Warning messages:
# 1: In mean.default(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
#  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
# 2: In mean.default(x, na.rm = na.rm, trim = trim) :
#  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
# 3: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

## getval
getval <- function(byrow) 
  skinny.data.mini[, match(skinny.data.mini$year.60[byrow],
  names(skinny.data.mini))][byrow]
skinny.data.mini$Y.60 <- sapply(1:nrow(skinny.data.mini), getval)
# Show Traceback

# Rerun with Debug
# Error in `[.data.frame`(skinny.data.mini, ,
# match(skinny.data.mini$forty.fam.head.laby.year[byrow],  : 
#  undefined columns selected
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
getval <- function(byrow) 
  big.data[byrow, match(big.data$year.60[byrow], names(big.data))]

big.data$Y.60 <- sapply(1:nrow(big.data), getval)
```

Or, if you really want to do it simply:

```
big.data$Y.60 <- mapply(getElement, name=big.data$year.60, data.frame(t(big.data)))
```

Comment: I clearly don't understand my dataset. Your getval function returned n of 1 in big.data$Y.60. The mapply returns this error: "Error in `[[.default`(object, name, exact = TRUE) :  subscript out of bounds"

Comment: can't seem to reproduce that. do you get an error when you try doing one row at a time: `big.data[1, match(big.data$year.60[1], names(big.data))]`

Comment: Apologies for wasting your time. It returns a value that makes no sense and I don't know how to search all columns, row 1, for that value. Nor how to search entire dataset. This mystery value is also the only value the getval() returned (n of 1 in comment one). Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you are working with a different dataset than the one you posted, you could help us understand it by posting the output of `dput(head(big.data))` onto your original question

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick vectorized approach

```
big.data$Y.60 <- big.data[cbind(seq_len(nrow(big.data)), 
                          match(big.data$year.60, names(big.data)))]
big.data
#   ID Y.1990 Y.1991 Y.1992 year.60 Y.60
# 1  1    100     NA    115  Y.1990  100
# 2  2    120    125    130  Y.1991  125
```

Comment: I think this returns big.data$Y.60 as "chr" rather than "num" as in original.

Comment: It gives the exact value class that in your original columns. Either way you can convert `big.data$Y.60` to numeric class using `as.numeric`

Comment: Apologies for first comment. I clearly don't understand my dataset. I received this error back: "Error in `[.data.table`(big.data, cbind(seq_len(nrow(big.data)), match(big.data$year.60,  :  i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #1611."

Comment: You have a `data.table` object there. You could convert it back to a `data.frame` for this puropose only using `setDF(big.data)`